# how to fix laravel Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

after one month of deploy my site in host and working normally now i get

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Définissez le package « ea-php72 » comme langage de programmation « PHP » par défaut.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
  AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
  AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 520M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Comment: What does the server error log tell you?

Comment: Just as @Dave said: you need to check the http server's error log file. That is where php errors typically get logged to (though there are exceptions). You _can not_ develop in a php web environment without monitoring that log file. Well, technically you can, but that would be like flying around inside a narrow cave, with  your eyes blind folded.

Comment: the error is  PHP Warning:  **require(/home/c1094833c/public_html/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/c1094833c/public_html/index.php on line 24** line 24 is require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: autoload.php is exist in vendor and the path is correct

Comment: Look closely at the require .... what is `/../` doing in the middle of the path? Does the vendor folder really reside above the public_html directory?

Comment: i fix it the problem is in htaccess in  the mine_models , thank you for help